# How can I map a JavaScript file path to ASP.Net MVC controller action?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an ASP.Net MVC 3 website that hosts a physical JavaScript file at this path: /bookmarklet/src.js. I'd like to make the content at the path to be the result of an MVC controller action so that I can make the output of this file dynamic.

How can I modify my website in order to send requests for this file to an action named "Src" on a controller named "Javascript"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it. You just need to add a custom route in your Global.asax file like this:

routes.MapRoute("bookmarklet",
                "bookmarklet/src.js",
                new { controller = "Javascript", action = "Src" });